Deriving the formula for arc length
I was trying to derive the formula for arc length as such:

Let d$x$ be a small change in $x$, let d$y$ be a small change in $y$, and let d$L$ be a small change in the arc length.

Then, by the pythagorean theorem, $(\text{d}x)^2+(\text{d}y)^2=(\text{d}L)^2$

Dividing both sides by $(\text{d}x)^2$ and taking the square root on both sides, we get $\sqrt{1+(\frac{\text{d}y}{\text{d}x})^2}=\frac{\text{d}L}{\text{d}x}$.

Hence, $L=\int \sqrt{1+(\frac{\text{d}y}{\text{d}x})^2}\, dx$, which is in fact the formula for arc length. However, I feel that this derivation is very abusive, as I am aware that the derivative is not really a fraction. I just want to know if differentials could be treated this way, and how come this abusive method seems to yield the correct result.

The specific notation for derivatives stuck on because it was more intuitive and treating them like fractions often yields correct results, for example see chain rule or the inverse function rule.

$dy=f'(x) dx$ Dividing by $d(x)$ just returns the derivative

If you truly want to derive the formula, you have to start with some definition of what arclength means. When you don't have that, anything you come up with cannot be rigorous. Your "derivation" is instead an informal argument that your formula encapsulates our intuitive understanding of the concept. At this point, the formula is then treated as a definition. Your derivation is sufficient for this. The generally accepted definition starts with defining the arclength of polygonal curves as the sum of the lengths of the line segments making it up. The arclength of a general curve (cont)

(cont) is then defined to be the maximum of the lengths of all polygonal approximations of the curve. which have all their vertices on the curve and in order. Starting with this, you can express the polygonal lengths as Riemann sums of the distance formula over various partitions, and then their maximum is the limit of the sums as the inverval lengths go to $0$. I.e., it is the Riemann integral of the differential distance formula you have produced.
